# Why isn't Buttonint changing? It's supposed to be added by 1 if something box is colliding with it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use this script for a multi activation door, aka.: If Buttonint value is 4 the Door should deactivate itself (Most of it is in another Script). However, I cant find the problem as to why Buttonint isn't changing its value if it collides with the correct box. I'm new to unity so please help....

Comment: Please add the script or the code you tried. Bear in mind that it's impossible to find any problem with the code if you do not post it here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the "Door" checks for Buttonint under Update().
2. Make sure it does dedect the collision, try a Debug.log("").
3. Check for rigidbody and collision settings, it is highly likely the reason.
4. Make sure it is a public value that is actively referenced.

It probably looks like that as far as I understood:

```
  if(Buttonint == 4){Door.SetActive("false")}
```